# Replace numbers in first section of file by result of calculation

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
     1 abcde
     2 00
     3 12
     4 12
     5 ghijkl
     6 jsaslm
     7 uawrns
     8 abcde
     9 \(%"!&/
    10 $!"$&/(
    90 !§%/(//
```

I want to replace all numbers greater than 3 in the first “column” (meaning the one that contains 1, 2 etc.). They should be replaced by the result of the calculation of the number modulo 3 - except for the numbers which are divisable by 3 (those should just be 3).
So the result should look like this:

```
     1 abcde
     2 00
     3 12
     1 12
     2 ghijkl
     3 jsaslm
     1 uawrns
     2 abcde
     3 \(%"!&/
     1 $!"$&/(
     3 !§%/(//
```

Formatting doesn’t matter much, but the way shown above would be preferred.

I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk for your updated question

```
awk '$1{$1=$1%3?$1%3:3}1' file

 1 abcde
 2 00
 3 12
 1 12
 2 ghijkl
 3 jsaslm
 1 uawrns
 2 abcde
 3 \(%"!&/
 1 $!"$&/(
 3 !§%/(//
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! I assume that if I change all the 3's with 80's, it will do the same calculation for 80?

Comment: @user146854 Yes that is correct

Comment: So I've just been testing around with slightly larger files. Only problem I notice, is that it will occasionally skip some lines (for example in a file consisting of 22 lines, I'm only getting 19 lines of output). I can't see why ...

Comment: This one fail if the first field is `0`, it will change line from `0 123` to `3 123`.

Comment: @cuonglm fixed even though i dont think that was actually a requirement

Comment: @user146854 Try it now, maybe it wasn't printing blank lines ?

Comment: Wasn't a requirement indeed, in my case it's only numbers > 0 :) This seems to have fixed the problem with skipping lines, though they weren't blanks.

Comment: @user146854 Weird, can't think of why that would happen unless they were blank, doesn't matter though now, the `1` at the end ensures every line is printed regardless :)

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{$1 = ($1 > n) ? ($1 % n) ? $1 % n : n : $1};1' <file
1 abcde
2 00
3 12
1 12
2 ghijkl
3 jsaslm
1 uawrns
2 abcde
3 \(%"!&/
1 $!"$&/(
3 !§%/(//
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't do exactly what I need it to do - I forgot something in my question, so I'll change it slightly.

Comment: Yes, this does it!